# CBPeripheralManager.updateValue vs CBPeripheral.writeValue?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

What exactly is the difference between writing characteristics over BLE using these two methods?  Are they the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apple documentation

CBPeripheralManager updateValue

> Sends an updated characteristic value to one or more subscribed centrals, via a notification or indication.

CBPeripheral writeValue

> Writes the value of a characteristic

Answer (score 2):

The two methods are different and which one you use depends on the role your app is playing in the BLE communication.

- If your app is acting as a peripheral then you will use `CBPeripheralManager.updateValue` to notify subscribed centrals that there is a new value for a characteristic.
- If your app is acting as a central then you will use `CBPeripheral.writeValue` to write a new value to a characteristic on a connected peripheral.